# Tap deprecated in Appium hybrid app

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I have issue with deprecated tap in Appium , because eclipse says that "tap" with coordinates is deprecated . I use :

```
TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction(driver);
TouchAction perform = touchAction.tap(524, 1735).perform();
```

to tap the location coordinates , and can`t find the new function for new "tap with coordinates"

Comment: An alternative to using `tap + coordinates` would be to search for the element and use the `click()` method.

Comment: The app is written with PhoneGap and cant find the element because they are view in views , and they dont have unique id or someting else . I tried with expecting xpath with appium inspector but the path is not correct or cannot be found . So the only alternative is using coordinates for the button i want to click (tap)

Answer (score 1):

Please check latest TouchAction class:
https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html

For tap on coordinates you can do:

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).tap(point(xPoint, yPoint)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the deprecated tap/press function is the 'longPress' function. Here's the function :

```
public T longPress(LongPressOptions longPressOptions) {
    ActionParameter action = new ActionParameter("longPress", longPressOptions);
    parameterBuilder.add(action);
    //noinspection unchecked
    return (T) this;
}
```

For more information, see : https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.java

Comment: I try the both ways previous , with 
new TouchAction(driver).tap(524, 1735).perform();
new TouchAction((MobileDriver)driver).press(524,1735).waitAction().release().perform();
but on both for "press" and "tap" is still methods tap(x,y) / press(x,y) are deprecated....

Comment: You're right, `press` also seems deprecated. From source I can see they have another alternative : `@deprecated use {@link #longPress(LongPressOptions)} instead`

Comment: Yes I saw that with the @deprecated use , but  i dont want to do it with the deprecated fucntions , but as it seems , they deprecated press/tab by coordinates , I its going to be with deprecated functions